# How to write a custom Jackson deserialiser with a dynamic class that is provided by another field

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, jackson2

I have this kind of object:

```json
{
    "type": "MY_TYPE",
    "value": "SomeCustomValue"
}
```

the actual type of the field `Value` can change, but I can know this type thanks to the field `type`, which is mapped to a Java enum.

The POJO associated is as follows:

```java
public class MyCustomObject<T> {

  public MyTypeEnum type;
  public T value;

  public MyCustomObject(MyTypeEnum type, T value) {
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

And my custom deserializer:

```java
public class MyCustomObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyCustomObject<?>> {

  public MyCustomObject<?> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

    MyTypeEnum type = MyTypeEnum.valueOf(node.get("type").asText());
    //CommonObjectMapper.get() returns a jackson object mapper
    Object value = CommonObjectMapper.get().convertValue(node.get("value").asText(), type.getType());

    return new MyCustomObject<>(data, value);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I can get the actual type from `type.getType`, but then I have to get another object mapper to do the actual deserialisation for my `value` field.

This works, but I'm pretty sure this is not the right way to do it ?

Comment: i would recommend a custom deserializer as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I am already using a custom deserializer, the code is in my post. In the article you linked, I don't see how tot reat this specific problem. Am I missing something ?

Comment: you need to provide the code of MyTypeEnum and CommonObjectMapper

Comment: @Tom sorry my comment was not really clear enough: I wanted to suggest, that you use the already registered deserializers instead of a new ObjectMapper for parsing the value attribute  (whether they are custom or default parsers, doesn't really matter) . I've added a complete answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-use already registered deserializers by using the JsonParser's codec and wrapping the node of the value attribute with a `TreeTraversingParser`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JacksonException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyCustomObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyCustomObject<?>> {

    protected MyCustomObjectDeserializer() {
        super(MyCustomObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public MyCustomObject<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        MyTypeEnum type = MyTypeEnum.valueOf(node.get("type").asText());
        Object value = p.getCodec().readValue(new TreeTraversingParser(node.get("value"), p.getCodec()), type.getType());
        return new MyCustomObject<>(type, value);
    }
}
```